# jquery selectors - more efficient way of obtaining the div after a td

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Can anyone propose a more efficient way of obtaining the div after a td.
Note that Table and Div repeats n times.

```
<table class="repeatingTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="repeatingCell">     
    <input type="text" class="listenerClass"/>
  <td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class='putSomeDataHere' >
<div>


var divToPutData = location.parent().parent().parent().parent().nextAll("div");
```

Comment: What do you mean "after a td" - do you mean the `div` that's closest to the `td`? This example doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: div after/closest to input text box. "Makes sense" is sometimes not a component of the client's requirements...

Comment: I didn't have an issue with the requirement; only the code and the wording of the question.

Comment: In your example, the `div` is outside of the table - you want the `div` that's closest to the table (and inherently, the input)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming you're navigating from the `input`...

```
location.closest('.repeatingTable').next();
```

See:

- [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)
- [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next)